# Why is setting ImageUrl of ImageButton in javascript doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net. I tried to change the image of an asp.net imageButton, using this code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/blueButton.png" Width="137px" Height="34px" onmouseover="this.ImageUrl='/Images/greenButton.png'" onmouseout="this.ImageUrl='/Images/blueButton.png"/>
```

It didn't work.
However, the following code did work:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/blueButton.png" Width="137px" Height="34px" 
    onmouseover="this.src='/Images/greenButton.png'" onmouseout="this.src='/Images/blueButton.png"/>
```

As you can see, I was using **src** instead of **ImageUrl**.

Why didn't the first one work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing server and client code. JavaScript runs on the client, and your `<asp:ImageButton>` runs on the server. These are two separate domains.

ASP.NET renders the `<asp:ImageButton>` as an HTML `<img src="/Images/blueButton.png">` on the server and sends it to the client, and then the mouse event can access it's DOM property named `src` at the client.

Look at the HTML source from your browser to see the difference between what you wrote in your ASPX file and the HTML the browser receives.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the <asp:ImageButton> is rendered to <input type="image" src="/Images/blueButton.png"> and not to <img src="/Images/blueButton.png">

Comment: I didn't check that, @cookya, I wanted to post a quick and easy answer, so I made an educated guess here. Didn't miss by much.